# Catch errors using redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-thunk to make API calls in my React app.

Every 30 minutes, the user's bearer token expires, and instead of forcing them to login again I call `auth/refresh`. This is a pain, because I need to check for `401 error` every time a call is made. Is there a way using redux/redux-thunk to check for this error in one place, rather than in every call?

I have the added problem that if multiple calls happen, the same refresh is called every time, so I end up refreshing the bearer token multiple times!

My action for refreshing the auth token:

```
export const refreshAuth = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(API.path + 'auth/refresh/?' + API.beaconAPI_client, { 'refreshToken': getState().login.refreshToken })
    .then(response => {
        dispatch({
            type: DO_LOGIN_REFRESH,
            userDetails: response.data
        })
    })
}
```

}

Using Axios, if an error occurs I do this:

```
.catch(error => {
  if(error.response.status === 401){
    this.props.refreshAuth()
    .then(response => {
        /* In the response, make the request again after auth is refreshed */
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Post your thunk action so we can see what's going on. Not sure why it would be called multiple times around the same time unless your code was strangely architected

Comment: @DominicTobias well it's a dashboard with components that each make API calls, so the checks need to be in place

Comment: You might want to consider redux sagas which has methods like `takeLatest` and many others for more advanced control flow. Or you could debounce the thunk `const refreshAuth = debounce((...args) => axios.post(...args), 5000);`

Comment: @DominicTobias debounce looks interesting, i'm not sure how to fully implement this into refreshAuth, though, could you provide a full example (perhaps as an answer?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Axios interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to have these handlers in one place.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
  switch (error.response.status) {
    case 401:
    // [Unauthorized] - Wrong or no authentication ID/password provided
    store.dispatch(actionToRefreshToken());
    break;
  default:
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have many different actions stored in different files which each get called at the appropriate times. Is there a simple way to catch all actions and run them through this *before* the subsequent actions occur?

Comment: Axios interceptors have nothing to do with Redux actions. They will just intercept your HTTP responses in this case. It's then up to you to reject Promises and dispatch the according actions.